# Java normal distribution with mean diff than zero and std deviance different than one

Tags: java, normal-distribution

My professor is simulating the arrival of clients to a bank.
It says that clients arrive following a normal distribution with 3.5 mean and 1.3 std deviance.

The problem is that I'm with some difficulties understanding why is using this code.
I believe that the code he provided is receiving a stream, mean and std to generate a random number

### Code

```
public class Random {

    private static double second=0;

    static double normal(int stream, double mean, double std){
        double v1=0, v2=0, y1, y2, x1, x2, w=2;

        if (second!=0 ){
            return second;
        }

        while(w>1){
            v1=2*RandomGenerator.rand(stream)-1;
            v2=2*RandomGenerator.rand(stream)-1;
            w=Math.pow(v1,2)+Math.pow(v2,2);
        }

        y1=v1*Math.pow((-2*Math.log(w))/w, 0.5);
        y2=v2*Math.pow((-2*Math.log(w))/w, 0.5);
        x1=mean+y1*std;
        x2=mean+y2*std;
        second=x2;
        return x1;
    }

}
```

My math lessons were many years ago so it's a bit hard to understand this normal distribution and after searched the internet to how calculate normal distribution I couldn't find any formula resembling to the code given.

So, these are my questions.

1. What does `second` does? It's some kind of protection?
2. How does this code uses the normal distribution? Can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: plese tell your professor he should learn to name his vars correctly

Comment: @chburd :) I also think that vars name should be more explanatory

Comment: Please also tell your professor that arrivals are usually modelled as Poisson distributions, not normal distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer the questions in reverse order. The central part of the method is a standard technique for converting two random variables drawn from a uniform distribution on [0, 1] into two random variables drawn from a normal distribution with a given mean and standard deviation. (It's called the [Box-Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-Muller_transform).) The `while` loop uses a generate-and-test technique to generate a random point (v1, v2) from a 2-D uniform distribution on the unit circle. The mapping from (v1, v2) to (y1, y2) converts the uniform distribution to a 2-D normal distribution with zero mean and unit standard deviation. This is then shifted and scaled to get (x1, x2) with the desired mean and standard deviation.

With a method of generating pairs of normally distributed variables now in hand, the rest of the code works as follows: if `second == 0`, this is a signal that new values need to be generated, so it falls through the `if` and generates a pair of values. It then saves one of the values in `second` and returns the other. The next time the method is called, it notices that there's a valid value in `second` and returns that immediately, instead of generating more values.

There's a major bug in the code: `second` should be reset to zero before it's value is returned; otherwise it will always continue returning the second random value (which won't seem so random after the second call). Even if that flaw were corrected, there's a second problem. Every other returned value will have zero probability of having value 0. Theoretically this isn't too bad because the probability of a normally distributed random sample having value exactly zero is...zero! However, it is still a flaw.

I'd rewrite the code as follows:

```
public class Random {

    private static double second;
    private static boolean secondValid = false;

    static double normal(int stream, double mean, double std) {
        double v1, v2, y1, y2, x1, x2, w;

        if (secondValid) {
            secondValid = false;
            return second;
        }

        do {
            v1 = 2 * RandomGenerator.rand(stream) - 1;
            v2 = 2 * RandomGenerator.rand(stream) - 1;
            w = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
        } while (w > 1);

        y1 = v1 * Math.sqrt(-2 * Math.log(w) / w);
        y2 = v2 * Math.sqrt(-2 * Math.log(w) / w);
        x1 = mean + y1 * std;
        x2 = mean + y2 * std;
        second = x2;
        secondValid = true;
        return x1;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would also remove all the static references since this is not thread safe.

Comment: @jontro - Removing the `static` qualifiers won't help thread safety. It will just mean that one can have multiple `Random` objects with private stashes of `second`. That's of limited utility, I think. Concurrent access to an instance of `Random` would still be unsafe.

Comment: Yes, sure. However if I use a static method I assume it is thread safe. If it is a mutable class I would know to either synchronize calls or make a new instance where it makes sense. Anyways, maybe this is out of scope for this question.

Comment: @jontro - I wouldn't assume a static method is thread safe simply because it is static. As it happens, [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random&28%29) is thread safe, but this is explicitly documented: _"This method is properly synchronized to allow correct use by more than one thread."_

Comment: @TedHopp Thanks for your explanation. Just to things. First, I've added another question. Second. You say this _This is then shifted and scaled to get (x1, x2) with the desired mean and standard deviation._ Where can I learn this? I understand what it does but dont understand why.

Comment: @Favolas - From the Wikipedia article Normal distribution: "a _N_ (_μ_, _σ_ ^ 2) can be generated as _X_ = _μ_ + _σZ_, where _Z_ is standard normal". Your additional question is unclear. Are you just trying to shift and scale a uniform distribution? The code you posted does not do that. It would be better to post a separate question, since it is a different topic.

Comment: @TedHopp Thanks. Removed the question. Wanted to know how can I generate random numbers with a uniform distribution given a strem, mean different than 0 and sdt different than 1. Since the code you provided uses a uniform transformation I tough it would be just a matter of reutilizing part of the code

Comment: @Favolas - Shifting and scaling one uniform distribution into another isn't anywhere near as complicated as going from uniform to normal and then scaling. For one, you don't need to do it in pairs (it's just a simple multiply and add) so you don't need `second` or any of the complexity needed for the case of a normal distribution.

Comment: @Ted. Ok. So it just doing the `do while` without `v2` removing `y1` and `y2` and doing `x1 = mean + v1 * std;`?. Sorry for this newbie questions but as stated on op, many years without math

Comment: @Favolas - No, there's no need for a `while` loop at all. It's a simple transformation. Please post a separate question about this. A uniform distribution is usually represented by the min and max of the range, not by mean and standard deviation. If you want to shift and scale by mean and standard deviation, it will take a bit of explaining. For info, read the [Wikipedia article on Uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29).